# Trigger used to update related record values

Tags: trigger

I am trying to update the related record after update. 
No error messages but the updates don't take place. I see the log messages at each section, **but I don't see that the newroom.put('Occupied__c', true ) sets value true.** . I am expecting the **Occupied__c** to be set. in those different cases. I do see the log messges that indicate that the code block is executed.

```
trigger ChangeAssignedRoom on lutd_Registration__c (after update) {

Id oldRoomId ;
Id newRoomId ;
Integer oldRoomOccQty;
Integer newRoomOccQty;

System.debug('====>>>> if Trigger.isUpdate <<<<====');
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

    for(lutd_Registration__c newRecord : Trigger.new){  // iterates through new versions of records
        lutd_Registration__c oldRecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id); // get the old version of the current record
        System.debug('Setup data');
        newRoomId    = newRecord.Assigned_Room__c;
        oldRoomId    = oldRecord.Assigned_Room__c;

        if(oldRoomId == newRoomId){ 
            System.debug('No Room Change');
        } else if (oldRoomId == null) { // update new room;
            System.debug('Assign New Room, += 1 ' );
            sObject newroom =  newRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(newRoomId);
            newroom.put('Occupied__c', true ) ;

            newRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));

        } else if (newRoomId == null) {  // update old room;
            System.debug('UnAssign Old Room, -= 1 ' );
            sObject oldroom =  oldRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(oldRoomId);
            oldroom.put('Occupied__c', false ) ;

            oldRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(oldRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));

        } else {          // update both
            System.debug('Assign  New Room, += 1 ' );
            sObject newroom =  newRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(newRoomId);
            newroom.put('Occupied__c', true ) ;

            newRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));


            System.debug('UnAssign Old Room, -= 1 ' );
            sObject oldroom =  oldRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(oldRoomId);
            oldroom.put('Occupied__c', false ) ;

            oldRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(oldRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));
        }
    }
} else {
    System.debug('Not Update');
}
```

}

Comment: You need to commit the change you're making to the related record using an explicit DML statement, otherwise you're just editing the record in memory

Comment: Your trigger is showing that it's only running in an `after update` context, so you shouldn't expect anything to be updated on the record within Salesforce.  Try `before update` to have the values on the trigger records updated in the database itself

Comment: @jonathanwiesel A simple: update newroom;  ?

Comment: @brian-miller does that include object that are not the triggered object?

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding of what your code is going to do here, I have simplified this to meet your related object update:

```
trigger ChangeAssignedRoom on lutd__Registration__c ( afterUpdate ){

    Map<Id, SObject> relatedObjectUpdateMap = new Map<Id, SObject>();

    if( Trigger.isUpdate ){

        for( SObject record : Trigger.old ){
            lutd__Registration__c oldReg = ( lutd__Registration__c ) record;
            lutd__Registration__c newReg = ( lutd__Registration__c ) Trigger.newMap.get( record.Id );

            Id oldRoomId = oldReg.Assigned_Room__c;
            Id newRoomId = newReg.Assigned_Room__c;

            SObject newRelatedRoom = null;
            SObject oldRelatedRoom = null;

            // change to the lookup ID
            if( oldRoomId != newRoomId ){

                // when we have a new room in the reservation (switched/added room)
                if( newRoomId != null ){    // update the new Room here once
                    newRelatedRoom = newRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject( newRoomId );
                    newRelatedRoom.put( 'Occupied__c', true );
                    this.relatedObjectUpdateMap.add( newRoomId, newRelatedRoom );
                }

                // if the reservation included an old room, it too needs to be updated
                if( oldRoomId != null ){
                    oldRelatedRoom = oldRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject( oldRoomId );
                    oldRelatedRoom.put( 'Occupied__c', false );
                    this.relatedObjectUpdateMap.put( oldRoomId, oldRelatedRoom );
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // update the rooms in the end. 
    if( !relatedObjectUpdateMap.isEmpty() ){
        update this.relatedObjectUpdateMap.values();
    }
}
```

As you can see, since this is a related record, we can update it in the end, but we want to make sure it is only 1 time being added to the list, so I used a map here. Judging from the scenarios that you had above, it appears to me like you could have been skipping the evaluation to the old room and new room in your else/if structure so I broke these out to their own evaluations to ensure that each was evaluated accordingly. In your execution, you may have seen this execute the `afterUpdate` block, but may not have necessarily reached your expected statement. By separating them, you are then able to ensure that you are adding to your final update records the old and new that were modified to meet their criteria based on this. If the old record is connected to another record in your trigger context, you will also see this room will be updated with the changes from that new assignment and no longer missed.

Comment: While I was missing "update" this is very helpful.  The actual problem is a little more complicated then the example because there can be several people assigned to the same room. The rooms have 'Occupied_Qty__c' and a 'Capacity__c' so a room is not 'Occupied__c' until  'Occupied_Qty__c'  =>  'Capacity__c' .

Comment: oh yeah, for sure - just giving a narrow example of my interpretation though. am sure there could be more evaluation needed for your other cases. I hope it gets you in the right direction